# Subversion becomes "svn_relpath_join: Assertion` relpath_is_canonical (component)' failed. "

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I check the branch in the repository browser(tortoiseSVN), it says "Could not convert'### error ###' into a number", and the branch and log cannot be checked.

It seems that there are 4360 revisions.

```
$ ls -l /path/to/repository/db/revs/4/
total 10844

// ...

-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache   10001 Jun 15 14:43 4358
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache    5049 Jun 20 12:05 4359
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache    5011 Jun 20 19:44 4360
```

Performs a repository integrity check.
Seems to be failing with revision 4344.

```
$ svnadmin verify /path/to/repository
* Verified revision 0.
* Verified revision 1.
* Verified revision 2.

// ...

* Verified revision 4341.
* Verified revision 4342.
* Verified revision 4343.
svnadmin: subversion/libsvn_subr/dirent_uri.c:1163: svn_relpath_join: Assertion `relpath_is_canonical(component)' failed.
Aborted
```

I'm not familiar with Subversion, but is this a broken revision?
I can't post details such as the contents of the file, is there a way to restore it?

Comment: svn recover completed successfully, but verify gives the same error content.

Comment: What version of `svnadmin` and TortoiseSVN are you using? What errors do you receive when you run an up-to-date (1.14.x) version of `svnadmin verify`?